# Exception while launching a compose task with Spring Cloud Data FLow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to launch a compose task with spring cloud data flow. The tasks are billrun and bilsetup mentioned in the docs. While launching I get the following exception:

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:jar:@dataflow.version@ from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:270)
at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolve(MavenArtifactResolver.java:352)
... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:jar:@dataflow.version@ from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:472)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:294)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:67)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
... 84 common frames omitted